# In TFS - How to access, execute and get the result of shared query programmatically in C#?

Tags: linq, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have written a shared query in TFS, 
How do I programatically access, execute any pre-defined TFS query and get the result of it programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I could get the answer in this below link

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx